# Searching text from a list in another file

Tags: command-line, grep, search, text, csv

Is there a grep-like program for Ubuntu that can search a text file, or batch of text files in a folder, for any occurances of words in another text file or a list like a csv file or an ods file or whatever.
So I have a folder with 50 text files and want to find any occurances of words on a list in another file containing 500 words, is there any way of doing this? Thanks!

Comment: `grep -f filename` will pull search strings from the named file. `man grep` is your friend.

Comment: I didn't know grep could do this, many thanks!

Comment: You can also use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution): `grep -R -f <(cut -d, -f2 ~/list.csv | head -3) ~/path`

Comment: That works too, even though I don't fully understand why! Thanks!